# i can't fix error in c using float type for car fee program example

Tags: c

I tried with this code but can't find way to resolve this problem.
I tried to change float type to int, or chaing indent doesn't fix either. If anyone can provide solution, that would be help me out.
my expectation is trying to get the right result for this code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  float hour, fee;
  hour = 5;
  fee = 20;
  
  if (hour > 4)
    fee = 20 + hour*30;

  printf ("Hour = %.2f\n",hour);
  printf ("Car Park Fee = %.2f",fee);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more info about your problem, like what it's printing or what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting an error like this

```
    3 | main()
      | ^~~~
```

then you have to specify a data type before main().
Your code will look like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float hour, fee;
    hour = 5;
    fee = 20;
  
    if (hour > 4)
        fee = 20 + hour*30;

    printf ("Hour = %.2f\n",hour);
    printf ("Car Park Fee = %.2f",fee);
}
```